# Vue redirecting. My code is note redirecting to the page i want to

Tags: vue.js

it is not redirecting to the page. What am I doing wrong here?

this method is getting all the data from the form and adding dynamic values to date and token.

```
methods:{
        addToApi() {
            console.log(this.data);
            crypto.randomBytes(20,(err,buff)=>{
                let token = buff.toString('hex');
                let sub = this.data.sub;
                let date = Date.now() + 3600000;
                let newData = {
                    sub: this.data.sub,
                    token: token,
                    date: date
                }
                axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/qrData",newData)
                    .then((res)=>{
//after sending the data to back end it should redirect to this route but it doesn't redirect
                   router.go('/');
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: check [Vue Router: Programing Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n), **router.go(n)**
This method takes **a single integer as parameter** that indicates by how many steps to go forwards or go backwards in the history stack, similar to window.history.go(n). for your use case, you should use **router.push**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [Vue Router: Programing Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n),

As the tutorial said:

**router.go(n)**

> This method takes **a single integer as parameter** that indicates by
>   how many steps to go forwards or go backwards in the history stack,
>   similar to **window.history.go(n)**.

For your use case, you should use [**router.push**](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort)

Comment: Even the router.push(‘/‘) is not doing anything. Page stays the same backend gets the data though.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The main problem is that you refer to `this` variable which in this certain case has different values over the scopes. The common solution is to create a new variable storing `this` as I did it in the first line of `addToApi()` method.</s>

Getting to the point, variable `router` is undefined in the method's scope. You should use `this.$router` which refers to the global router object. And as `this` variable loses its value in `then` function (change of scope), you want to use `vm` variable I defined. So your code should finally look like this below:

As pointed in the comment, arrow functions do not carry `this` variable.

If you want to redirect to a particular route you should use `$router.push` method instead. ([`go` method was used in Vue Router's older versions and renamed to `push` in 2.x](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.1))

```js
methods: {
  addToApi() {        
    crypto.randomBytes(20, (err, buff) => {
      let token = buff.toString('hex');
      let sub = this.data.sub;
      let date = Date.now() + 3600000;
      let newData = {
        sub: this.data.sub,
        token: token,
        date: date
      }
      axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/qrData", newData)
        .then((res) => {
          //after sending the data to back end it should redirect to this route but it doesn't redirect
          this.$router.push('/');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    })
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I managed to fix it. ‘this’ works without having to declare it to a separate variable. I didn’t put a response back from the backend kept the page static. worked perfectly after i put a response. Thank you though.

Comment: _["An arrow function expression `() => {}` ... does not have its own `this`"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)_

Comment: @EmileBergeron Good to know. Thanks.